# PHP: session_start() doesn't work on Server, but on localhost?

Tags: php, ajax, database, forms, session

I searched now for hours but couldn't find any solution. I hope you can help me.

I created a website and tested it with xampp and eververthing works well, but now I uploaded it on a server and I could realize that the `session_start()`  does not work.

This is the code of my index.php:

```
<?php 
            session_start();
            echo session_status()."<br>";
            echo "SessionID: ".session_id();

        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); 

?>

<html>


    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="screen" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              // Add smooth scrolling to all links
              $("a").on('click', function(event) {

                // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
                if (this.hash !== "") {
                  // Prevent default anchor click behavior
                  event.preventDefault();

                  // Store hash
                  var hash = this.hash;

                  // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
                  // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
                  $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
                  }, 800, function(){

                    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
                    window.location.hash = hash;
                  });
                } // End if
              });

              $(".loginField").click(function() {
                  $(".loginDetails").toggle("slow");
              });

              $(".profilName").click(function() {
                  $(".profilMenu").toggle("slow");
              });

              $("#middleLoginButton").click(function() {
                  $(".middleLoginForm").toggle("slow");
              });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- getting UserData, if available -->
        <?php

            //delete Session Data, if logout
            if (isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == 1) {
               echo "SessionID Logout:".session_id();
               session_destroy();
               //header("Location:https://www.whocando.eu");
            }

            function autoload ($className) {
                if (file_exists('classes/'.$className.'.php')) {
                    require 'classes/'.$className.'.php';
                }
            }

            spl_autoload_register("autoload");

            if ($_GET['falsePassword'] == 1) {
                $falsePassword = 1;
            }

            if ((empty($_POST['userName']) || empty($_POST['password'])) && empty($_POST['registration'])) {
            // after Login Check! 
            } elseif (isset($_POST['userName']) && isset($_POST['password']) && !isset($_POST['registration'])) {
                $loginCheck = new loginParser();
                $userID = $loginCheck->loginChecker($_POST['userName'],$_POST['password']);
                $_SESSION['userID'] = $userID;

                $abfrage = new dbQuery("SELECT ID,name, firstName FROM db764570417.userdata WHERE ID = $userID");
                $userName = $abfrage->fetchData('ID','name');
                $userFirstName = $abfrage->fetchData('ID','firstName');

            // already logged in Check!
            } elseif (isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
                $userID = $_SESSION['userID'];

                $abfrage = new dbQuery("SELECT ID,name, firstName FROM db764570417.userdata WHERE ID = $userID");
                $userName = $abfrage->fetchData('ID','name');
                $userFirstName = $abfrage->fetchData('ID','firstName');
            // after Registration Check!
            } elseif (isset($_POST['registration'])) {
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $vorName = $_POST['vorname'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $uni = $_POST['uni'];
                $geburtstag = $_POST['gebDatum'];
                $password = $_POST['passwort'];
                $confirmedPassword = $_POST['confirmPasswort'];
                $gebDatum = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($geburtstag));
                $abfrageEmail = new dbQuery("SELECT ID,email FROM db764570417.logindata");
                $userEmails = $abfrageEmail->fetchData('ID','email');

                if ($password != $confirmedPassword) {
                    header("Location:https://www.whocando.eu/registration.php?fault=passwordNotMatched&name=".$name."&vorname=".$vorName."&email=".$email."&uni=".$uni."&gebDatum=".$geburtstag);
                } elseif (in_array($email,$userEmails)) {
                    header("Location:https://www.whocando.eu/registration.php?fault=emailAlreadyUses&name=".$name."&vorname=".$vorName."&email=".$email."&uni=".$uni."&gebDatum=".$geburtstag);
                } elseif (empty($name)) {
                    header("Location:https://www.whocando.eu/registration.php?fault=nameMissing&name=".$name."&vorname=".$vorName."&email=".$email."&uni=".$uni."&gebDatum=".$geburtstag);
                }elseif (empty($vorName)) {
                    header("Location:https://www.whocando.eu/registration.php?fault=vorNameMissing&name=".$name."&vorname=".$vorName."&email=".$email."&uni=".$uni."&gebDatum=".$geburtstag);
                } elseif (empty($email)) {
                    header("Locationhttps://www.whocando.eu/:registration.php?fault=emailMissing&name=".$name."&vorname=".$vorName."&email=".$email."&uni=".$uni."&gebDatum=".$geburtstag);
                } elseif (empty($uni)) {
                    header("Location:https://www.whocando.eu/registration.php?fault=uniMissing&name=".$name."&vorname=".$vorName."&email=".$email."&uni=".$uni."&gebDatum=".$geburtstag);
                }elseif (empty($geburtstag)) {
                    header("Locationhttps://www.whocando.eu/:registration.php?fault=gebMissing&name=".$name."&vorname=".$vorName."&email=".$email."&uni=".$uni."&gebDatum=".$geburtstag);
                } elseif (empty($password)) {
                    header("Location:https://www.whocando.eu/registration.php?fault=passwordMissing&name=".$name."&vorname=".$vorName."&email=".$email."&uni=".$uni."&gebDatum=".$geburtstag);
                } elseif (empty($confirmedPassword)) {
                    header("Location:https://www.whocando.eu/registration.php?fault=confirmedPasswordMissing&name=".$name."&vorname=".$vorName."&email=".$email."&uni=".$uni."&gebDatum=".$geburtstag);
                } else {
                    include ('dbConnection.php');

                    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
                    $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    $sqlCode = "INSERT INTO db764570417.logindata (name,email,password)
                      VALUES (?,?,?)";

                    $userNameDB = $vorName."".$name;

                    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($sqlCode);
                    $statement->bind_Param('sss',$userNameDB,$email,$hashedPassword);
                    $statement->execute();
                    $newUserId = $mysqli->insert_id;

                    $_SESSION['userID'] = $newUserId;

                    $sqlCode = "INSERT INTO db764570417.userdata (ID,name,firstName,firstLogin,lastLogin,birthDate,email,university)
                          VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($sqlCode);
                    $statement->bind_Param('isssssss',$newUserId,$name,$vorName,$date,$date,$gebDatum,$email,$uni);

                    $statement->execute();
                    //header("Location:index.php");

                    $userID = $newUserId;
                    $userFirstName[$userID] = $vorName;
                    $userName[$userID] = $name;
                }
            }

        ?>
```

If I load the page there will be no session ID created, but if I test exactly the same code on localhost, it works. 
I thought there were an issue with the server and uploaded a file with the following code:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
    echo session_status();
    echo "SessionID: ".session_id();
}

echo "SessionID: ".session_id();
?>
```

I am now completely confused and don't know what mistake I did.

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Enable error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php what does it throw back seeing you're using it?

Comment: Check for /tmp/ directory and permissions of it.

Comment: Are you running the same version of PHP on your localhost as your server?

Comment: Check for errors on the query, we don't know what those functions do. You should also add `exit;` after each header.

Comment: Contents of HTTP headers must be URL encoded (`urlencode()`) plus you should exit the program like Funky49 said.

Comment: You should most likely move almost all the php code to the top of the file or even into a separate php file that will be "included" at the top. Once you get to the part in the source code where the html starts <html>...</html> you can't use functions like header() or session_start() anymore because the page's headers have already been sent. Also like mentioned if you are redirecting someone with a Location header you should exit() after the header is being set. As for you session problem itself, maybe check if your local php has session autostart enabled and your server doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Exec following code and find `session.save_path`

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Just add right permissions to this path